# Report of systems with 32/64bit Office installations within a domain

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, active-directory

Our domain has a KMS activation server and a number of virtual desktops, regular desktops, and laptops which all have Office 2010 or 2013 installed. Most of them should be 32-bit Office but I know that some of them are 64-bit. Is there any way (using system center, powershell, active directory, ???) to get a readable report of which computers have which version of Office installed?

I used a typical application monitor but it gave a huge list of office related components as well including things that look like they are bridges for 64-bit office components even though those machines have 32-bit office installed.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Get-InstalledSoftware_32_And_64.ps1. It's incredibly useful and can do what you need. You can even set it up to add extension attributes to computer objects with a bit of extra scripting, then leverage those extensions with other AD components. But that's beyond the scope of this answer.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Installed-70d0c0f4

Here's an easy way to get your lists. 
**Note**: This relies on `Get-InstalledSoftware_32_And_64.ps1` being setup with `Import-Module` prior to running the following script.

```powershell
# Import AD module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
# Setup array of computer names
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select -Expand DNSHostName
# foreach loop - do stuff...
foreach ( $computer in $computers ) {
    $output = Get-SoftwareList -Computername $computer | Select-String "Microsoft Office 2013"
    if ( $output -match "64" ) {
        echo "$computer >> Office2013-64_Installs.txt"
    }
    elseif ( $output -match "32" ) {
        echo "$computer >> Office2013-32_Installs.txt"
    }
    else {
        $recheck = Get-SoftwareList -Computername $computer | Select-String "Microsoft Office"
        echo "$Computer :: $recheck >> Office2013_Check_ErrorLog.txt"
    }
}
```

The error log will list computers that either don't have Office 2013 installed, or have the wrong version installed. You can do a lot more validation, but this will get you started.